# Android - Selecting / highlighting a drawn path in canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am creating a basic drawing application. I implemented basic shapes and colour change option. Currently I am storing each path drawn into a List.

Now I want to add an edit option works in following manner:

> When the user click on a drawn shape (Path) it should be highlighted
>   and user should be able to edit the shape.

How can I achieve this..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold the bunch of Points you put into your Path.

Bruteforce routine should be like below:

1) Touch down event has triggered.
2) Calculate the Euclidean distance from every Points in each Path to the touch point.
3) Find the shortest distance, and determine the distance is short enough.
4) If so, choose the Path to be selected.
5) Edit the selected Point, or other Points as you wish.

If you have 20 Paths which each of them has 100 Points, you have to calculate Math.sqrt() at least 2000 times which ensures the laggy screen.
You can choose the Manhattan distance method instead of Euclidian for performance.

I suggest you to use OpenCV features.